# How to display a image on mouse over in silverlight data grid

Tags: silverlight

I need to display a image on mouse over only in silverlight 5.
Can any one please help me.
Give me any idea how to achieve it...

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colDeleteContent" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Delete Content" Width="100" CanUserResize="False">
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <StackPanel x:Name="spDeleteContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">                                                            
    <Image x:Name="imgDeleteContent" Source="Assets/Images/close.png" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgDeleteContent_MouseLeftButtonDown" Cursor="Hand"/>                                                            
   </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Neon

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, OnFocus set your images Visibility Visible and on FocusLeft set Collapsed basically of your main element.

But I see that it is on DataTemplate on your sample.

So There are some ways I imagine.

1)Create a new component instead of element in DataTemplate such as

```
namespace ProjectBus
{

    public class StackPanelHasHiddenImage : Control
    {
        //You may don't need dependency property
        //It supports bindability
        #region dependency property
        public static Image GetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (Image)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
        }

        public static void SetMyProperty(DependencyObject obj, Image value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(Image), typeof(StackPanelHasHiddenImage), new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(null));
       #endregion

        public Image Image
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
        }
        protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml use like

```
 <DataTemplate>
   <local:StackPanelHasHiddenImage Image="/ProjectBus;component/blabal.png"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

2) Use GotoStateAction behaviour
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723953%28v=expression.40%29.aspx but I see that its in a DataTemplate and using this may not be easier.

3) MainElement.FinChildByType  < StackPanel >().FirstOrDefault() is not null then add your focus and unfocus handler to this element on your codebehind. But this is a method I mostly avoid to use.

Its a bit harder because its in a template so your named object in template can't be seen on your codebehind.

Hope helps

Comment: i tried your code. what is namespace for <local:StackPanelHasHiddenImage />. Pls help...

Comment: I edited the part 1) I suppose your the class StackPanelHasHiddenImage class's namespace is ProjectBus in your XAML just add  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectBus" where xmlns's are defined. local is not a reserved word this is what I made up. You may collect your controls in a namespace such as ProjectBus.Controls then in your xaml you code declaratively <controls:MySuperBox> Sure before use like that adding xmlns:controls:"clr-namespace:ProjectBus.Controls" required.

Comment: I will try your updated code and send you my feedback... Thanks

Comment: what are you meaning as inbox in the line typeof(Inbox)... I didn't understand by that..

Comment: Ohh sorry, It must be the name of your class. In here its "StackPanelHasHiddenImage". The first part is autogenerated with propa. You may don't care the region dependency property.I just wanted to show you formal way of component creation.

Comment: Have a look this sol. http://davutgurbuz.name.tr/downloads/HiddenImagePanel.rar a complete sol. But I realize there is something I missed. In Silverlight if a component's Visibility Collapsed your given width and height properties will not be meaningfull. So you need to manage mouseEnter event on a top level visible container. I applied to a border. You may embed this border inside your control.Or you may manage mouseOver state where this datatemplate applied. Hope helps!

Comment: thanks for your effort i will try your sample application, and i send you my feedback.